# Java Code Not Executing

Tags: java, android

The code below is not executing. I'm calling it as `NameManager.main(fsitem);` from my main class. Not even debug is showing up in stack trace and it does not create the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class NameManager {
...
public static void main(ArrayList<String> fsitem) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fsitem.size(); i++) {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getName() + "/" + fsitem.get(i));
            if (root.canWrite()) {
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    Log.d("NameManager.java",
                            (root.getName() + " exists and is writable."));
                    File namefile = new File(root, ".name");
                    FileWriter namewriter = new FileWriter(namefile);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(namewriter);
                    out.write("image_"
                            + (i++)
                            + "%n(Autogenerated Name)%nroyale1223@gmail.com");
                    out.close();
                } else {
                    Log.d("NameManager.java : ",
                        (root.getName() + " already exists."));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("NameManager.java : ",("Error!! Not Writable!!"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()
                    + "/" + fsitem.get(i)));
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android at all, but as it's derived from Java, a question: are you sure that such signature of `main` method is allowed?

Comment: Is fsitem empty by any chance? Add some logging *before* the loop to show the size...

Comment: Its not empty. The code compiles, signature must be allowed??

Comment: Are you trying to `hide` the `static main` method? the `main` is the the entry point of the application run. so you should definitely know what you're doing. http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OverridingVsHiding

Comment: I tried to run the method in another name first. But since that failed I switched to main as last resort. It's working now, see the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code checks wether root exists and can be written (.canWrite()), and does not exist (!.exists()). Both together is not possible, so nothing can happen.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Method signature of main must be: `public static void main(String[])` not `ArrayList<String>` as an argument. See ["Hello World!" from Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).</s>

---

**EDIT**: After discussion on chat with OP it turned out that he called `NameManager.NameManager(fsitem);` instead `NameManager.main(fsitem);`.

Comment: This is not his main class. He is calling this method himself as he says in his second sentence.

Comment: I'm new to java will you please tell me how to make `ArrayList<String> fsitem` to the format `String[] args`

Comment: @BinoyBabu Are you sure `NameManager.main(fsitem);` is called and executed? Try put a brakpoint on first line (`for`) and debug your code or even put `System.out.println("it's in!");` befor loop...

Comment: `Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), ("b4 name mgr"));
  NameManager.main(fsitem);
  Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), ("after name mgr"));` Tried this, both messages shows up in stack.

Comment: Ok, so now put `Log.d(<something here>, fsitem)` inside your `main` to say if `fsitem` is empty or not.

Comment: The whole method main is not being called. I tried renaming it, debugging it from 1st line, but this code never executes. I can however call another method from this class.

Comment: added `Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), fsitem.toString());`. Its not empty, has one element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8169/discussion-between-xaerxess-and-binoy-babu)

Comment: No, it compiles fine, shall I post my main class here?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities:

1. your `fsitem` array is empty.
2. `(root.canWrite())` failes.
3. Are you sure the method is being called?

Comment: 1. Its not, 2. Should show up in stack, 3. Yes it's being called `NameManager.main(fsitem)`;

Comment: if 2. failes, it wouldn't show up in the log, there is no else clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

> use this instead of your code, hope will help